# Sending data on specified ip & port

Tags: java, c#, .net, iot, data-transfer

I already have traffic between two devices that are both connected on internet(with different public static ip) on completely different networks. Both devices transfer data on a specified port, and are currently up and running very well. That being said i would like to add up my computer (random pc) to transfer​ and receive data with both devices. 
Note that both devices are programmed by some other third party and i cannot modify nothing, but both contain options for data transfer to a second ip address.
Since receiving data is MAYBE less complicated as the two devices are capable of transmitting/receiving  I would like to  know how i can transfer data from my pc to these two devices?

Any clue?

Sorry for the long post and my English since it's not my native language.

Comment: I don't think stack overflow is right for this question.

Comment: Your PC is a Client and the devices are Servers.  use one of the client examples on msdn webpage.  You didn't specify what protocol the devices arre using.  Is it a Web application or TCP?  msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jdweng none of the devices are related on server/client services.. The two devices mentioned in the post simply transfer/receive data via Public ip addresses nothing more. And the transfer protocol is udp, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Common Mistake.  There are 7 layers to Networking and some objects have different meaning at different layers.  Services are application layers.  A Socket is a connection layers.  So a connection has a client and server also.  The server is a slave device and is a listener.  The client is a master device that connects to a listener (server).  The two devices are server-listeners.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your explanation... But where do i start ? Can you please give me a clue ?